# Closed 4-manifolds with uncountably many differentiable structures

Tags: examples-counterexamples, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

I know that $\mathbb{R}^4$ admits uncountably many differentiable structures and I was wandering what happen if we consider closed (or just compact) 4-manifolds. Are there any closed (or compact) 4-manifolds with uncountably many differentiable structures? And with countably many?

Comment: Yes, I want to know if there are any uncountable (or countable) family of closed (or compact) 4-manifolds which are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic.

Comment: Donaldson showed that Dolgachev surfaces (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolgachev_surface) have countably many smooth structures.

Comment: Answered at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/171978/closed-4-manifolds-with-uncountably-many-differentiable-structures in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a summary of comments.

Your question was answered [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/171978/closed-4-manifolds-with-uncountably-many-differentiable-structures) in a comment by Ryan Budney. In the nutshell: The categories DIFF and PL are equivalent in dimension 4 (this is due to Kirby and Siebenmann, but one can easily spend a year trying to understand their proof). A PL structure on an n-manifold is equivalent to a "combinatorial triangulation", i.e., a triangulation where the link of each simplex is combinatorially homeomorphic to the closed n-ball. Since there are only countably many finite simplicial complexes, it follows that there are only countably many closed differentiable 4-manifolds.

Furthermore, I think, it is also true in higher dimensions that there are only countably many smooth closed manifolds (even though, DIFF $\ne$ PL), but I would have to check this.

Lastly, according to Qiaochu Yuan's comment, Dolgachev surface (which is a closed 4-manifold) admits countable infinitely many smooth structures.